# Thumbnail buttons and taskbar progress bar

Tags: c++, winapi, functional-programming

When I find tutorials for making thumbnail buttons or showing taskbar progress bar, they all are written in OOP style. But I'm currently learning to write applications with Win32 API and I didn't use C++ very often. And what I've learned so far, create applications with functional style. So my questions are, if someone knows tutorials, where these features of Windows 7 are written in functional style or does someone have tips for me? Which windows messages I have to handle and which functions I have to call?

Comment: These APIs are exposed via COM. Yes you can consume them with C code. But that's painful. It will be so much easier to consume the COM from C++.

Comment: I agree with you. But the problem is, that I'm currently learning. So it is very difficult to me to write OOP code while the book shows me functional style.

Comment: It will be next to impossible for you to call those functions using C style code